# Standalone HTML Snippets Libary for eCommerce

Tags: library, html, css, ecommerce

**Purpose**

I have been tasked with coding a front end site from set of mock ups provided by a graphic designer.

The site is an eCommerce site. Whilst I will be using some html griding framework, I don't want to use an 'eCommerce Template' as I feel there will be too much hacking to get it to look exactly like the designers mock up.

Whilst I don't want to use a fully fleshed out template, what I'm hoping to do is to find some basic html/css 'snippets' that can be used as a starting point for some of the standard eCommerce elements (cart, checkout, product page etc)

Are there any libraries that provide these basic elements? Like bootstrap is an overall html framework, I guess I'm looking for a more specific eCommerce framework.

**Requirements**

- Must have html/css for eCommerce element (cart, checkout, product page)
- CSS must at a minimum provide layout of the elements
- CSS preprocessor files desirable
- The styling must be very plain (think bootstrap) to allow custom styling to be easily applied.
- Can be open source or commercial

Comment: Why would Bootstrap not work? Is there something specific that Bootstrap is lacking?

Comment: as far as I know it doesn't have a library of eCommerce snippets out of the box. I basically don't want to write all the boiler plate code to get a basic cart, checkout, product page etc up and running. Just want to something that has a bunch of these standard elements as snippets that i can just paste in.